# Unrecoverable Access DataBase File Password

Tags: microsoft-access, password-protection

How can I set a password for an Access Database file, so that no user can recover this password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are utilities to break this security:
http://www.snapfiles.com/get/dbpwsniffer.html

So I wouldn't trust an access password to protect your data.

We store the data in SQL server and use SQL Native encryption which relies on NTFS authentication to decrypt.

Comment: Please More Details About Sql Native Encryption ...

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3483931/SQL-Server-2005-Security---Part-3-Encryption.htm

Comment: The cited URL for the so-called "Database Password Sleuth" is limited to "Access 95/97/2000/2002". Not sure why A2003 is omitted, but certainly A2007 is omitted because the database password encryption was strengthened big time in A2007. But I have heard that there's enough information stored in the file header to crack it. In my opinion, the database password serves no purpose whatsoever except to give people a completely false sense of security.