# Reputable Access Password Recovery

Tags: microsoft-access, open-source, password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove the password from Microsoft Access file](https://superuser.com/questions/180392/remove-the-password-from-microsoft-access-file)

Bypassing Access database security is a trivial matter.  There are many freely available tools that can recover or crack password-protected Access databases, and several questions on this site ([1](https://superuser.com/questions/226282/access-xp-or-access-2000-password-recovery), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/55189/password-recovery-toolkit), [3](https://superuser.com/questions/106149/unrecover-access-database-file-password)) have links to them.

The problem is that many of these tools are not open-source (e.g., Cain and Abel) or come from sources that may not be entirely reputable. For example, the guy who makes Cain and Abel may well be trustworthy, but he's just some guy, and I can't verify that the tool is clean.

My usual tactic when dealing with shady or unverifiable tools is to clone a VM and sandbox the tool in that VM.  But that's a pain, and it would be better -- especially for business use -- to work with a tool that I know can trust.

Are there any free Access password tools that are open-source or which come from highly trustworthy sources, like Microsoft itself?  (ME and Vista jokes aside, Microsoft won't ship you malware.) If it's just source code or an algorithm that's available, I'd be happy to implement it myself.  Access 2003 seems to be the most useful target, but a tool gets bonus points for handling other versions.

Comment: Although your intentions might be good (really I have no idea), I think some people might smell this as fishy.  That put asside, what file version of Access are you using?

Comment: Edited. I've seen many, many legitimate business IT scenarios where the data's rightful owner is unable to access it (no pun intended), ranging from inexperienced/apathetic developers leaving behind obscure projects with no documentation, to incompetent employees locking data away as insurance in case they get fired.